# Reopen a question

Tags: discussion, specific-question, exact-duplicates

[Who can view which circles in Google Plus?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/17244/who-can-view-which-circles-in-google-plus)

I just was notified that the above question is popular. It should be reopened. It is NOT a duplicate. I am asking if there is a way members of a circle only view the people of their circle.

[Can my Google+ contacts know in which circle I put them?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/17029/can-my-google-contacts-know-in-which-circle-i-put-them)
is well different from my question. That question asks about the name of the circle in which one resides.

Comment: Did you edit the question to make sure the distinction is clear?

Answer (score 3):

I am afraid that I do not agree with you, your question is a duplicate. [This post](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/17030/5095) provides an answer to your question.

You want to know if people in a circle you have created can see other people in that circle?

> The Circles feature works one-way, meaning that their members can't see if they are part of a Circle or not.

If the other moderators disagree then I am happy for the question to be reopened but in my opinion it is a duplicate.

Comment: Nope, I am asking that If I have added you to, let say, my stackoverflow circle then only my stackoverflow members should be visible to you. Without letting you know that you are in my stackoverflow circle.

Answer (score 1):

Just because a question is popular doesn't mean it should be reopened.

Barry is right, your question is a duplicate. However, it *is* phrased differently to the original and as such is still a useful question to have on the site. People search for slightly different terms when looking for the same thing and having two (or more) questions that ask the same thing but in a different way is a good thing.

Jeff addresses good duplicates in [this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/).

Your question is just closed, not locked. It can still gain up-votes and badges, so all is not lost :)